# -bash: Applications/mvim: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I am getting a weird error with the `mvim` script that is supposed to start the MacVim interface.

See below for the issue. `/bin/sh` is just fine, `mvim` was `chmod +x`'d, other `/bin/sh` scripts run fine... I'm at a loss here.

```
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ file Applications/mvim 
Applications/mvim: POSIX shell script text executable
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ head Applications/mvim 
#!/bin/sh
#
# This shell script passes all its arguments to the binary inside the
# MacVim.app application bundle.  If you make links to this script as view,
# gvim, etc., then it will peek at the name used to call it and set options
# appropriately.
#
# Based on a script by Wout Mertens and suggestions from Laurent Bihanic.  This
# version is the fault of Benji Fisher, 16 May 2005 (with modifications by Nico
# Weber and Bjorn Winckler, Aug 13 2007).
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ chmod +x Applications/mvim
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ Applications/mvim 
-bash: Applications/mvim: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

Below you can see that `/bin/sh` scripts run fine...

```
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ vim test.sh
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ chmod +x test.sh 
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ ./test.sh 
hi
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/sh

echo "hi"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, so it seems OS X thought it was a good idea to quarantine my script, for some reason, and not tell me about it.

```
jan@MacBook-Pro ~ $ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Applications/mvim
```

fixes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I too had a similar problem that was seemingly caused by something different and I just couldn't put my finger on what it was.

This is an edit to my original answer.  I have now remove my back and forth attempts to understand the causes.  I suggested it was caused by symbolic or hard links that somehow changed due to some file or disk actvity.  But all I seemed to do was make the simple solution somewhat confusing.

Regardless of what happened it is an easy fix - just create a new copy.  A file copy won't work as that just copies whatever that file had become.  Use `cat` instead.

```
   $ cat weatherHistory.sh > weatherHistory2.sh
   $ rm weatherHistory.sh
   $ mv weatherHistory2.sh weatherHistory.sh
   $ ./weatherHistory.sh. # Executes as expected
```

This is on MacOSX 10.14.6.

Comment: The @ as part of the permissions doesn‘t indicate a hard link

Comment: You are right, its a symbolic link.  I'll fix the answer.

Comment: I think you are mixing this with `@` at the end of the filename Maybe have a look at `man ls` for an explanation of what a `@` *at the end of the permissions* means :-)

Comment: `man ls` ...

`-F      Display a slash (/) immediately after each pathname that is a directory, an asterisk (*) after each that
             is executable, an at sign (@) after each symbolic link, an equals sign (=) after each socket, a percent
             sign (%) after each whiteout, and a vertical bar (|) after each that is a FIFO.`

Comment: Also in `man ls` is **The Long Format** - `l     Symbolic link.`

Comment: I discussed these in the answer.

Comment: Hi @nohillside I've corrected the answer and answered the question.  Could you restore the vote.

Comment: You see, by leaving it at -1 it means users will ignore the answer when in fact it is correct.  Doing everyone else a disservice.

Comment: From the part of the man page you've quoted: " Display a [...] immediately after each pathname". Your `ls` output doesn't contain a `@` after the pathname though. The relevant part of the man page rather is `If the file or directory has extended
     attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '@' character.`

Comment: From what I can see your fix (`cat file > newfile`) works to resolve whatever issues script had. It isn't related to the use of (symbolic or hard) links though.

Comment: I guess my warbling suggests that I am not clear on the cause.  I will edit this to hone in on the solution.