# mount is adding a quarantine flag, causing: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted - but not the usual suspects

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, mount, environment-variables

OK, I'm having a similar problem to: [-bash: Applications/mvim: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/bash-applications-mvim-bin-sh-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted) - but it's not the same problem. I'm getting the same result.

I've already verified that it's *not* the com.apple.quarantine flag.

It's *not* the line endings (script was created just from vi). I can execute the script by using:

```
bash simpleshell.sh
```

Here's the results:

```
fawkes:tmp kylar$ vi simpleshell.sh
fawkes:tmp kylar$ chmod +x simpleshell.sh 
fawkes:tmp kylar$ ./simpleshell.sh 
-bash: ./simpleshell.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
fawkes:tmp kylar$ cat simpleshell.sh 
#!/bin/bash
export FOO=Hey
echo $FOO
fawkes:tmp kylar$ which bash
/bin/bash
fawkes:tmp kylar$ bash simpleshell.sh 
Hey
fawkes:tmp kylar$ xattr -l simpleshell.sh 
fawkes:tmp kylar$
```

UPDATE: I don't believe it's the filesystem being mounted as noexec. I've tried running the script in 3 different places: /tmp, ~,  and /source.

UPDATE2: Ok, after more digging - I created the script inside /source, which is a mounted dmg. That's where I ran xattr -l and found nothing. When I cp'd the script to ~ and ran xattr -l, it then had the com.apple.quarantine xattr. On a hunch, I looked at the mount attributes for /source and found:

```
/dev/disk1s9 on /Volumes/code (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners, quarantine, mounted by kylar)
```

So when I mount this dmg it's getting set as quarantine. How can I tell mount not to mount it with the quarantine flag? Once I removed the flag in ~, the script ran fine.

Comment: If you don't get your answer here, consider asking on UNIX and Linux SE.

Comment: I may just cross-post it anyways - this is basically blocking me from getting any work done :(

Comment: Are you able to run other programs on the same filesystem in a similar fashion?  That is using `chmod +x file.sh; ./file.sh`.  Maybe that filesystem's mounted with the "noexec" flag.

Comment: @MaxRied Please don't suggest people cross post - we would rather migrate it if the OP feels it was asked here in error and belongs on another site.

Comment: It might be helpful to rewrite your question to only ask about how to tell mount to not use the quarantine flag, since you now determined that was your actual problem. Also, I don't know how to disable it for a particular volume, but to disable quarantine altogether, `defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO`.

Comment: OK, I have solved it. There was a com.apple.quarantine xattr set on the .dmg file. I had to unmount it, clear the xattr and then remount the dmg. GAH. @houbysoft: thanks for the tip on turning it off entirely.

Comment: Great it works, I'd suggest that you add an answer and briefly explain how you solved the issue. This will help others and prevent your question from showing up in the Unanswered>no answers top ten. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script was being run from inside a .dmg that had the quarantine flag set on it. When the .dmg was mounted, it was mounting it with a quarantine flag that is inherited, but doesn't show up. I unmounted the .dmg, removed the quarantine flag, and re-mounted it, and all was well.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had a similar problem, and it was driving me crazy: A Perl script, created by Vim (or even cat), with no quarantine xattr associated with it. However, the script resided in a mounted sparse bundle. After reading this page, I unmounted the filesystem and looked inside the bundle: There was a file named "token" in there that had the "com.apple.quarantine" xattr set. Once I deleted the xattr and remounted the sparse bundle filesystem, my "bad interpreter" problem with the Perl script went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution: cat configure.sh > test.sh
then run test.sh.

Turns out to be an editor problem:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3733470?start=30&tstart=0

Comment: No, it's not a solution for my situation. As the question reads, I was using vi to create the scripts. That's an interesting link though.