# Why does macOS set xattr com.apple.quarantine, when saving a shell script on a usb stick

Tags: terminal, usb, bash, metadata

### Problem

macOS sets xattr **com.apple.quarantine**, when I edit and save the file myscript.sh on a usb stick

We're on the USB stick

```
[stick128] pwd
/Volumes/stick128
```

The textfiles xattributes before being edited

```
[stick128] ls -la@ myScript.sh 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 schmelzer  staff  28 22 Okt 02:16 myScript.sh
com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_vmtpkn3xxtzmlwr5m34qap3z4a  185
```

The textfiles xattributes after being edited and saved

```
[stick128] ls -la@ myScript.sh 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 schmelzer  staff  30 22 Okt 02:20 myScript.sh
com.apple.quarantine    24 
com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_vmtpkn3xxtzmlwr5m34qap3z4a  201
```

### Cause

??

### Temporary Solution

Remove the xattr manually

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine myscript.sh
```

Thanks to 
[-bash: Applications/mvim: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/bash-applications-mvim-bin-sh-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But he next time, I edit the file, the xattr get's added again by whom?

- by the texteditor?
- by macOS (as part of the SIP System?)

### My Environment

- macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.6
- Texteditor: CotEditor, Version Version 3.2.2 (203)
- USB Stick: SanDisk 128GB Connect Wireless Stick, plugged into the USB Port

### My research 1

Q: Is the problem only on the USB stick? Or is it on my harddisk, too?

A: Problem is not on the harddisk. Only on the USB stick

Details for research 1

We're on the macs harddisk, where macos is installed

```
[Desktop] pwd
/Users/schmelzer/Desktop
```

The textfiles xattributes before being edited

```
[Desktop] ls -la@ myScript.sh 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 schmelzer  staff  30 22 Okt 02:20 myScript.sh
com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_vmtpkn3xxtzmlwr5m34qap3z4a  201
```

The textfiles xattributes after being edited and saved

```
[Desktop] ls -la@ myScript.sh 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 schmelzer  staff  28 22 Okt 02:25 myScript.sh
com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_vmtpkn3xxtzmlwr5m34qap3z4a  201
```

Testresult

The quarantine xattr has not been added to the file. Thus the problem does not exist on the harddisk. Only on the usb stick.

### My research 2

Q: Is there a file with the quarantine flag set, on the USB stick?
[mount is adding a quarantine flag, causing: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted - but not the usual suspects](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/mount-is-adding-a-quarantine-flag-causing-bin-bash-bad-interpreter-operatio/96079#96079)

A: Yes, there were many.

Details for research 2

List xattributes of all files on the stick

```
xattr -r /Volumes/stick128/
```

Remove the xattribute com.apple.quarantine from all files on the USB stick

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Volumes/stick128
```

Try provoking the error again, by editing and saving the myScript.sh file

Result

- No error
- The xattr com.apple.quarantine is not beeing added to myScript.sh

### My research 3

Q: When I use a different Texteditor, does the problem remain the same?
[mount is adding a quarantine flag, causing: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted - but not the usual suspects](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/mount-is-adding-a-quarantine-flag-causing-bin-bash-bad-interpreter-operatio/96079#96079)

A: Not tested

### My research 4

Just for reference:

- This post describes the "bad interpreter: Operation not permitted” Error", which happens, when you try to execute a shell script with the xattr quarantine flag set.
- [-bash: Applications/mvim: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/bash-applications-mvim-bin-sh-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted/49590#49590)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This solved it for me

Q: Is there a file with the quarantine flag set, on the USB stick?
[mount is adding a quarantine flag, causing: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted - but not the usual suspects](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/mount-is-adding-a-quarantine-flag-causing-bin-bash-bad-interpreter-operatio/96079#96079)

A: Yes, there were many.

#### Howto do it

List xattributes of all files on the stick

```
xattr -r /Volumes/stick128/
```

Remove the xattribute com.apple.quarantine from **all** files on the USB stick

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Volumes/stick128
```

Try provoking the error again, by editing and saving the myScript.sh file

#### Result

- No error
- The xattr com.apple.quarantine is not beeing added to myScript.sh

Comment: Even with sudo this was failing for me, until I realized I needed to temporarily add “Full Disk Access” permissions to my terminal